# Java cast e converter

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo, cast

Como faço para converter `ValueCallback<Uri>` para `ValueCallback<Uri[]>`?

Comment: veja se isso pode lhe ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296734/image-uri-to-bytesarray?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Não... mas obrigado.

Comment: Não dá pra fazer um simples _cast_ porque os tipos não são compatíveis. Forneça mais detalhes a respeito do problema para que possamos ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer essa conversão por 3 motivos.

1 - Você só pode fazer o cast se houver uma relação de extends ou implements entre as classes.
Ex:

```
public class Animal {
```

}

```
public class Cachorro extends Animal {
```

}

Nesse caso, você pode fazer um upcasting:

```
Animal animal = new Cachorro();
```

ou um downcasting:

```
Animal animal = new Cachorro();
   Cachorro cachorro = (Cachorro) animal;
```

Aqui está um detalhe. O cast só irá funcionar, porque a instância do objeto animal é um Cachorro. Se porventura você fizer dessa forma:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Cachorro cachorro = (Cachorro) animal;
```

O downcasting irá falhar.

2 - Em java, podemos fazer algo desse tipo:

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<Animal> arrayList = (ArrayList<Animal>)list;
```

Mas se tentarmos fazer isso aqui:

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Cachorro>();
```

Será lançada uma exception. O java não converte o tipo que está sendo utilizado no Generics, somente o objeto que está usando o Generics que nesse caso são as Collections.

3 - Você está tentando converter Uri para Uri[]. Isso não faz sentido.
Não pode converter um objeto comum em uma lista. Pelo menos não via cast da linguagem. O que você pode está querendo fazer é quebrar uma única Uri em várias Uri. Isso não é uma conversão de tipos. Nesse caso, você vai precisar criar um converter.